# Plotting normal distribution curve with the lower left region shaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, normal-distribution

I am new to javascript and was wondering if anyone could help me with plotting a normal distribution curve in javascript with the lower left region shaded (eg: area under 17th percentile shaded). Thank you in advance!

here is the link to a picture of how i want my graph to look like: 
http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0005791612000110-gr1.jpg
or 
http://sdrv.ms/LLEFQg

Comment: Do you have an example of the image you want to create?

Comment: i've included a link to the image i want to create (:

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [jStat](http://www.jstat.org/demonstration) plugin, it supports shading and has a pretty robust statistics engine.